# Recursive call on a lazy value using LiveData and ObserveForever

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have the following class structure:

Activity > ViewModel > DataManager > ApiManager

I'm trying to use `LiveData` to share objects between layers. The DataManager and the ApiManager are kotlin `object` so they haven't any reference to activities. In order to implement the "callback" I'm using `observeforever` in the DataManager and ApiManager in the following way:

```
fun doStuff(inParam:String, inParam2:String)LiveData<Pair<String,Boolean>>{
   var reponse:MutableLiveData<Pair<String,Boolean>> = MutableData()
   val requestResponse: LiveData<Pair<String, CustomType>>= ApiManager.doStuff(inParam1, inParam2)
   requestResponse.observeForever {
        //Do some task here
        response.value = Pair("ok",true)
   }
   return response
}
```

In practice it works as expected, with this structure I get my activity updated using the `LiveData`. My problems appear when I export the signed apk. During this process is called the `VitalLint` and in spite of the signed apk is generated it is showing the following error pointing to the activity when I read the `LiveData`:

```
Error:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive call in a lazy value under LockBasedStorageManager@351242ee (<unknown creating class>)
```

The error is associated with this line:

```
val status:Boolean = either.second
```

I suspect the this could be related with my way to implement the observe with the `observeForever` but I don't find any other way to observe without having a lifecycle aware component in my object classes. Any ideas?